# error with execute queryExecuteFactory with parameter model and query

Tags: android, file, sparql, jena

I'm running a SPARQL query against a Model read from a file, and having a problem in that the results are not being shown.  When I try to print to show each solution in the ResultSet, I'm stuck in

```
QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(queryString, model);
```

It does not show the query, but instead:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.QueryExecutionBase@4272a730
```

This is my code:

```
  package com.monead.androjena.demo;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileInputStream;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.util.List;

  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
  import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

  public class SparqlCodeClass {
public String queryRemoteSparqlEndpoint() {
    /**
     * Use the SPARQL engine and report the results
     * 
     * @return The number of resulting rows
     */
    StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
    try{
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("storage/extSdCard/foaf.rdf"));

    // Create an empty in-memory model and populate it from the graph
    Model model = ModelFactory.createMemModelMaker().createModel(null);

    //--results.append(model);
    //Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    model.read(in,null); // null base URI, since model URIs are absolute
    //results.append(model);
    //--results.append(model);
    // Set the query
      String queryString = "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
            "PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>"+
            "SELECT DISTINCT ?name"+
            "WHERE {"+
            "?x rdf:type foaf:Person ."+
            " ?x foaf:name ?name"+
            "}"+
            "ORDER BY ?name";

    // Set the SPARQL endpoint URI
   // String sparqlEndpointUri = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    results.append(queryString);
    // Create a Query instance
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
    results.append(query);
    // Limit the number of results returned
    // Setting the limit is optional - default is unlimited
    query.setLimit(10);

    // Set the starting record for results returned
    // Setting the limit is optional - default is 1 (and it is 1-based)
    query.setOffset(1);


   // QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(sparqlEndpointUri, query)ว
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(queryString, model);
    results.append(qe);
    // Execute the query and obtain results
    ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();
    results.append(resultSet);
    // Setup a place to house results for output


    // Get the column names (the aliases supplied in the SELECT clause)
    List<String> columnNames = resultSet.getResultVars();

    // Iterate through all resulting rows
    while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
        // Get the next result row
        QuerySolution solution = resultSet.next();

        // Iterate through the columns
        for (String var : columnNames) {
            // Add the column label to the StringBuffer
            // results.append(var + ": ");

            // Add the returned row/column data to the StringBuffer

            // Data value will be null if optional and not present
            if (solution.get(var) == null) {
              //  results.append("{null}");
            // Test whether the returned value is a literal value
            } else if (solution.get(var).isLiteral()) {
             //   results.append(solution.getLiteral(var).toString());
            // Otherwise the returned value is a URI
            } else {
             //   results.append(solution.getResource(var).getURI());
            }
            results.append('\n');
        }
        results.append("-----------------\n");
    }

    // Important - free up resources used running the query
    qe.close();
    in.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
           results.append("Error from not found");
        }
    catch(IOException e){
       results.append("Error from io");
    }


    // Return the results as a String
    return results.toString();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do with the `StringBuffer results`.  The query is a Java object, and generally you work with it until you execute it and get back a ResultSet.  You're iterating over the ResultSet correctly, but that's not what you usually want to do for generating human readable output.  The easiest way to print out a ResultSet nicely is to use the [ResultSetFormatter](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFormatter.html).  In your case, instead of iterating through the Solutions in the ResultSet, you would just do:

```
ResultSetFormatter.out( resultSet )
```

and you'll get the results in a nice ASCII tabular format, e.g.:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| individual                            | type       | label      |
===================================================================
| <file:/nature/life/Animal#kingdom>    | wo:Kingdom | "Animals"  |
| <file:/nature/kingdom/Animal#kingdom> | wo:Kingdom | "animalia" |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: sorry again, i have another question. if i want to send value the resultset to another class. what should i do . Thank you.

Comment: First, if either of the replies so far have answered your question, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to let other users know that it worked for you.  Then, if you an additional question, you should post it as a separate question, since each question on StackOverflow should be about a single issue.  This also helps other users find it, whereas a question in the comments is unlikely to be found.  Additionally, you'll have much more room to describe your question.

Comment: i try follow your suggestion but the result just show the name of title not a content or all value.

Comment: @user2467994 Your SPARQL query isn't returning any values; it needs to be adjusted.  Please post your data in the question.  I'd try removing one of the triple patterns (i.e., `?x rdf:type foaf:Person` or `?x foaf:name ?name`) and see if the other gets any results.  At this point, though, you're able to run the query and to print the results (even though there aren't any yet), so _this_ question is probably done, and you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and post your query and data as another question.

Comment: It's work and i found this sparql query have something wrong. and i test with other query then it's work.

Comment: @user2467994 Yes, I understand that.  Why your SPARQL query doesn't return any values for your data is _a different question_.  Please ask a new question showing the SPARQL query and the RDF data that you have, and you will probably get an answer about how to fix the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print the query execution object.  It's a java object.

Try, for example:

```
ResultSet rs = qe.execSelect() ;
ResultSetFormatter.out(rs) ;
```

There are lots of output formats and options.  See the documentation at http://jena.apache.org/.